# How could record the fps from kinect

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using rqt to subscribe the image view from openni,
How could I know the current fps of the video?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199926/how-could-record-the-fps-from-kinect/) by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a terminal:

```
rostopic hz /your/camera/topic/image_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1